# Sudden Issue in setting image border

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, padding

I have to show circular profile picture  with border around it. I have a background image for border. I am setting image "src" with padding of 3 dp.
My Image view in XML looks like:

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/pic_iv"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/blank_avatar"
   android:padding="3dp"
   android:scaleType="fitXY" 
/>
```

I am setting image to this image view using "setImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)" programatically.

I googled and tried setting property

```
android:cropToPadding="true"
```

but this is also of no use. Padding is being ignored. so no border is shown around image.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: could you please tell me , what excatly is the problem ?

Comment: Exact issue is that by using this code, it was working till yesterday... but now padding is being ignored. I tried setting fixed dp values as height and width of ImageView too.

Comment: So what you are trying to do is give your image a border  by giving it a background and a padding to make the background appear but it doesnt appear ?

Answer (score 1):

this is what i have done to make the borders

1st - in the layout file i did the following :

```
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:background="#123456"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

2nd - in my activity i used the same method you are using to change the image "setImageBitmap(bitmap)" like the following :

```
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.aaaa);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

and i got a  image with the padding around it with 10dp like the image attached.

[image]

Hope that helps .

Comment: I am also using similar xml and code. May be issue arised due to setting height and width wrap content. I fixed these values depending on screen size as I have to show image in a prticular view of fixed size and the problem solved.

Thankyou all...

Answer (score 0):

Change properties of *ImageView* `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to `android:scaleType="center"` or `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` and try again .

Hope this will work .